# Calculating Residues and singularities

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, residue-calculus

We haven't done many full examples with residues so just wondered how you would answer the following questions for example:

Classify the type of singularity for f and determine the residue of f at the point indicated:

$$f(z)= \frac {e^{iz}}{z^4}$$ at $z_0 = 0$

and $$f(z)= \frac {1+e^z}{\sin(z) + z\cos(z)}$$ at $z_0 = 0$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The residue of $f$ at $z_0$ is by definition the coefficient $c_{-1}$ in the serie $$f(z) = \sum_{k=-r}^{+\infty}c_kz^k$$

If the Laurent serie of $f$ begin at least at $k = 0$ the singularity at $z_0$ is said *removable*. If the serie begin at some $-r < 0$ the point $z_0$ is called a pole of $f$. Else, the singularity is called an *essential singularity*.

**First function**

At $z=0$, $g(z) = e^{iz}$ is holomorphic and the Laurent serie is the same as the Taylor serie, namely $$g(z) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{i^kz^k}{k!}$$

Obtaining the Laurent serie of $f = \frac{g(z)}{z^4}$ is then easy : $$ f(z) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{i^k z^{k-4}}{k!}$$
In particular, the coefficient of $z^{-1}$ is just $\frac{-i}{6}$.

**Second function**

Here, the denomiator is more complicate. You can see first that $1 + e^z$ is holomorphic near $0$ (in fact it is holomorphic on $\mathbb C$) and $\sin(z) + z\cos(z)$ have a zero of order one. What does that mean "f has a zero of order one at $z_0$" ? Simply that I can write $f(z) = (z-z_0)g$ where $g(z_0) \neq 0$. Here it's clear that the zero of $\sin(z) + z\cos(z)$ is of order one (just look the Taylor series).
So the pole of $f$ will be of order one, because $$f = \frac{1+e^z}{\sin(z)+z\cos(z)} = \frac{1}{z}\frac{1+e^z}{\psi}$$ where $\psi$ is holomorphic and nonzero at $z_0 = 0$.

You can therefore apply the "quotient rule" : if $\psi$ is holomorphic, non-zero at $z_0$ and $\phi$ is holomorphic with a zero of order $1$ at $z_0$ then $Res_{z_0}(\frac{\psi}{\phi}) = \frac{\psi(z_0)}{\phi'(z_0)}$ which gives to you $$Res_{z_0}(\frac{1+e^z_0}{(\sin(z)+z\cos(z))'_{\mid z_0}}) = \frac{2}{1 + 1} = 1$$

(In fact they are plenty of such rules, you have to know some of them for be able to compute different kind of residues).

In general, the most simple for quotient is to compute the order of the zeroes to the numerator and denomiator and using formula for quotients. Compute directly Laurent series works sometimes. In general, a bit of thinking is better that tedious and useless computations.

Example :

> Without paper or pen, compute the residue at $z_0 = 0$ of $$\frac{z^2}{cos^8(z)} + \frac{e^{z^2}}{z^4}$$

**Hint:**

> The function is even : all the odd coefficients $c_{2k+1} = 0$. In particular $Res_0(f) = 0.$

---